# Is there a numpy function to change values in an array by index without for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

I have done the code below:

```
size = int(len(np.where(features_temp != 0)[0]) * k_value)
idx = np.random.choice(np.where(np.in1d(features_temp, np.array(list_amino_numbers)))[0], size=size)
for i in idx:
   features_temp[i] = np.random.choice(list_amino_numbers, p=probabilities[:, list_amino_numbers.index(features_temp[i])].tolist())
```

This code works well, but I think that it can run faster, mainly in the for iteration. There is some operation that I can change the for iteration?

Code Explanation: I am trying to change the values of features_temp in the indexes that are values different from 0. Each index can be changed many times, and the number of possible changes depends on the number of values different from 0 and a constant (it is saved at idx). In the end, each index depends on a matrix (probabilities), and in the matrix, each line i and column j defines the probability of each j be changed to i (so, I need to use the column values).

Input Example:

```
features_temp = np.array([3, 2,  0, 2, 1])
k_value = 1.5
list_amino_numbers = [1, 3, 2]
probabilities = np.array([[0.9, 0.2, 0.3], [0.07, 0.7, 0.5], [0.03, 0.1, 0.2]])
```

In this case, size = 6.

Comment: can you add a minimum reproducible example? A small input, expected output, and some details around what you are trying to do, as its not very clear right now.

Comment: map( lambda i; (np.random.choice(...i...), idx ) ?

Comment: does `features_temp[idx]` work?

Comment: I added some datails what I am trying to do and one example

Comment: @hpaulj it works, I merged your answer with the answer of Mark Lavin, thank you all